# How can I have access into *argv[ ] in C?

Tags: c, arguments

Say that I have this part of code. If user does not enter the file names as command line arguments I want to ask him again so as to enter them now but as it seems I cannot have access in argv[1] and argv[2]. For example when the first scanf is executed segmentation fault occurs. But in this case how can I read the arguments and place them into argv[1] and argv[2]?
Thanks in advance for your help!

```
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        printf("You did not enter two files.\n");
        printf("You can now enter those two files.\n");
        printf("file 1: ");
        scanf("%s", argv[1]);
        printf("file 2: ");
        scanf("%s ", argv[2]);
    }

    printf("%s\n", argv[1]);
    printf("%s\n", argv[2]);

    FILE *file1 = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    FILE *file2 = fopen(argv[2], "r");
}
```

Comment: Just as a side note: Using the format string `"%s"` in `scanf` is generally not safe. You may want to read this: [A beginner's guide away from scanf](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html)

Comment: What happened if you pass 3 or more arguments? (for example, `myprog myprog.exe foo.exe c`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A segmentation fault occurs because length of the argv array is determined when the user runs the program. If you run a program like this:

```
./programName
```

argv is only 1 element long. It's impossible to access argv[1] or argv[2] after that. Still, You can get the necessary data and save them in regular variables.

Answer (score 2):

You don't. As the popular phrase goes, every problem in computer science can be solved by an extra layer of indirection. In this case the indirection is that you define a clean interface for opening a file and pass it a `char const*`. But this pointer doesn't have to be `argv[1]`.

You have to malloc your own buffer (because **none** exists) and write to it. Using `scanf("%s",...)` for this purpose will likely create a buffer overrun as you cannot know in advance how large your buffer needs to be.

*Edit*: Every single answer given to you suggesting to use `char buffer[NUMBER]` as the buffer for `scanf` **will blow up in your face**.

Comment: And it might be pointed out how hilarious it is to see the buffer size escalation in the answers given to this question; First, one person suggests 20 bytes, then a second person suggests the exact same solution but with 100 bytes, then a third copy but now with 255 bytes. Unsafe buffer handling is unsafe, regardless of how ridiculous you make your buffer size.

Comment: Posix-only (but that's a lot of systems): `scanf("%ms", &str);` simplifies everything.

Answer (score 0):

`Argv` is passed from console and you pass it while executing your program.

First, you have to compile it with, for example:

`gcc program.c -o program`

And then execute it with arguments, for example:

`./program arg1 arg2`

If you wish to wait for a user to enter parameters for your program through the console you should use regular variables.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `argv[1]` and `argv[2]` are only valid if `argc >= 3`.
Thus accessing them is of course wrong.

Then if you want to read the arguments from stdin, you must make sure that you have memory where those strings are kept.
You might use something like

```
char filename1[20], filename2[20];
char *f1, *f2;
if (argc == 3) {
  f1 = argv[1];
  f2 = argv[2];
} else {
  f1 = filename1;
  f2 = filename2;
  /* add code to read into filename1 and filename2 */
}
/* use f1 and f2 */
```

You can see that I only reserved 20 bytes for each filename, which was arbitrary chosen by me.
It is critical here to not write more than 20 bytes into those arrays (including the terminating NUL char), so you should not use scanf like this.

You can see that this is not really straight-forward in C so there is also not an answer that suites all purposes.

Edit: also be sure to never write into any `argc[...]` memory, as it is supplied from the system. Although not marked `const` I would rather consider it as such.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this because `argv[1]` and `argv[2]` are NULL pointers (if they even exist in the array), so you can't access them.

You need to approach the problem from a different way.

Instead of trying to change members of `argv`, assign them to other variables that hold the file names.

```
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    char file1[100], file2[100];
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        printf("You did not enter two files.\n");
        printf("You can now enter those two files.\n");
        printf("file 1: ");
        scanf("%s", file1);
        printf("file 2: ");
        scanf("%s ", file2);
    } else {
        strcpy(file1, argv[1]);
        strcpy(file2, argv[2]);
    }

    printf("%s\n", file1);
    printf("%s\n", file2);

    FILE *file1 = fopen(file1, "r");
    FILE *file2 = fopen(file2, "r");
}
```

Note that I made some assumptions about the length of a filename.  Adjust as necessary.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm pretty certain that they don't exist at all. They are definitely not NULL pointers. If they were, you could do `argv[1] = malloc(size)` which you cannot.

Comment: @klutt Actually, I think `argv[1]` would exist and be NULL.

Comment: That seem strange. Assume it's true, how big is the array?

Comment: @klutt I believe it's `argc+1`, and `argv[argc] == NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Placing them in `argv` is the wrong approach. Much better to do something like this:

```
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    char f1[255];
    char f2[255];
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        printf("You did not enter two files.\n");
        printf("You can now enter those two files.\n");
        printf("file 1: ");
        scanf("%s", f1);
        printf("file 2: ");
        scanf("%s ", f2);
    } else {
        strcpy(f1, argv[1]);
        strcpy(f2, argv[2]);
    }
    FILE *file1 = fopen(f1, "r");
    FILE *file2 = fopen(f2, "r");
}
```

You should avoid writing to `argv`. That's in general a bad idea.